# How can I tell Xcode 4 what syntax coloring to use for a file type it doesn't (appear to) know?

Tags: xcode, opencl

I'm working with some OpenCL code in Xcode 4. I don't want to compile the code with Xcode - that's done dynamically by the C++ code. Xcode 4 doesn't know about OpenCL syntax coloring. How can I tell it to apply C syntax coloring instead?

(It's not just for coloring. It also gets indenting wrong etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xCode Menu [Editor]->[Syntax Coloring] doesnt work?

Comment: I really wanted a rule that would automatically do this every time I open a file with extension .cl but you did answer my question as stated.